# Spring Kafka: Attempt to join group failed due to fatal error: The configured groupId is invalid

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, listener, consumer

I am currently writing a Kafka Listener, and when I run it, it gives me tons of errors like this:

```
2018-03-12 14:55:17.866  INFO 19440 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=] (Re-)joining group
2018-03-12 14:55:17.866 ERROR 19440 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=] Attempt to join group failed due to fatal error: The configured groupId is invalid
```

Is this because the consumer configuration is not set up correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the property called:

```
`spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=my-fancy-consumer-group-id`
```

Comment: Hi I was thinking about the same thing. I use .yml and I had     consumer:
      group-id: test in it but it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you add it to yml? Can you add an example? I assume something wrong is yml config.

Comment: thanks, it helps, but why is "group" property ignored in @KafkaListener  and do we need to specify it at all?